# how to convert from import to require in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have to use a module - `webpage-capture`. In that its mentioned as import module. How I can use it with require. Please help.

```
import WebCapture from 'webpage-capture'
const capturer = new WebCapture()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use object destructuring to get a specific element from a module.

```
const { WebCapture } = require('webpage-capture');
```

Comment: Looking at source code I'd say it should be without curly braces, but I didn't check it.

Comment: Afaik import ... from just selects a specific export

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to get the destructuring to work as posted by Sebastian above. Looking at the source of webpage-capture I noticed this:

```
var _default = WebpageCapture;
/**
 * Export available devices names
 */

exports.default = _default;
```

So based on that I had to get the class from the `default` property of the exported object. Not sure if this is the best practice, but it worked for me:

```
const WebpageCapture = require('webpage-capture');
const capturer = new WebpageCapture.default();
capturer.capture("https://google.com");
```